# Is this the correct way to write a function template which accepts a function pointer with a variable number of arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I have the following code,

```
class ODBCFuncCall // Line 67
{
public:
    ODBCFuncCall(SQLHANDLE stmt, SQLHANDLE conn) : m_stmt(stmt), m_conn(conn) {}

    virtual ~ODBCFuncCall() {}

    template <typename... A>
    void RunStatementFunction(SQLRETURN (*in_func)(SQLHSTMT, A...), A... args)
    {
        in_func(m_stmt, args...);
    }

    virtual const char* GetFunctionName() = 0;

    virtual void Setup() = 0;
    virtual void Run() = 0;
    virtual void Cleanup() = 0;

protected:
    const SQLHANDLE m_stmt;
    const SQLHANDLE m_conn;
};
```

which I'm trying to compile with VS2012 SP4. It's barfing on it completely, here's a sample of the errors I'm getting:

```
Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : ')' \ODBCTask.h 75
Error   4   error C2065: 'A' : undeclared identifier    \ODBCTask.h 75
Error   2   error C2065: 'in_func' : undeclared identifier  \ODBCTask.h 75
Error   5   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '...'    \ODBCTask.h 75
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'    \ODBCTask.h 74
Error   7   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'  \ODBCTask.h 80
Error   3   error C2275: 'SQLHSTMT' : illegal use of this type as an expression \ODBCTask.h 75
```

It compiles fine when I comment out 'RunStatementFunction'.
The syntax seems to be correct to me, from what I can find by googling similar things...

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Variadic templates aren't available in VS2012, but they are in VS2013, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: bah, thanks. I thought that they had been introduced in VS2012. Oh well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is correct: [see it in action on ideone](http://tinyurl.com/odyffrd).

Variadic templates are only available in VS 2012 when using the November 2012 CTP. That introduced a separate toolset, which must be selected in the project properties. It should compile with that.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues I see.  First vs2012 does not support variadic templates, outside of the experimental CTP which should not be used in production code

Second you should perfect forward the arguments to your function pointer.

```
template <typename... As,typename...Ts>
void RunStatementFunction(SQLRETURN (*in_func)(SQLHSTMT, As...), Ts&&... args) 
{
  in_func(m_stmt, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

which should eliminate all overhead from the helper function in optimized builds.

vs2013 supports variadic templates.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Perfect forwarding wouldn't be helpful in my case since this was going to be for ODBC functions, which all take arguments which are efficiently copied.

Comment: @bwmat the original code would copy them twice if `A`s are value types.  If they are cheap to copy, ok: but why rely on that?

Comment: @Yakk, I trust the compiler to optimize away a copy of primitive types if it's possible to do so. In general though, what you're saying makes sense.